# How to choose a pattern for java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter when the time is of this format: "Jan 17 2019 03:38:06 GMT+00:00"

Tags: java, time, datetimeformatter

I have the following code:

```
try {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xxx");
    logger.debug("formatter: " + formatter);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(rtime, formatter);
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Failed to parse device time [" + rtime + "] ", e);
    }
}
```

`rtime` here is `Jan 17 2019 03:38:06 GMT+00:00`

Debug is printing out

```
formatter: Text(MonthOfYear,SHORT)' 'Value(DayOfMonth,2)' 'Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)' 'Value(HourOfDay,2)':'Value(MinuteOfHour,2)':'Value(SecondOfMinute,2)' ''GMT'Offset(+HH:MM,'+00:00')`
```

The error is :

```
Failed to parse device time [Jan 17 2019 03:38:06 GMT+00:00] 
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Jan 17 2019 03:38:06 GMT+00:00"
```

I tried a few patterns and it is always failing.
Could someone help?

Comment: the format is not dependent on 'what time it is'. It depends on what you need to get. what type is rtime?

Comment: rtime is a String. I have a method that takes epoch time as argument my goal is to get the epoch time using zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli()

Comment: I copied and ran your code, it works fine here. as @user16320675 suggests, check your locale.

Comment: It is working fine now after adding `Locale.ROOT`. Thanks guys for the help.

Comment: This can’t be right. You are catching `DateTimeParseException`, but your output reports a `java.text.ParseException`. That output cannot come from that code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major problems in your `DateTimeFormatter`:

- the missing `Locale`, which may cause the `Locale.getDefault()` to be used and that one may not know the abbreviation (e.g. a `Locale.ITALIAN` would expect `gen` instead of `Jan`)
- the wrong pattern letter for the time zone (the `String` contains an outdated offset notation, *hours from GMT*)

You can parse it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String rtime = "Jan 17 2019 03:38:06 GMT+00:00";
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss VV", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println("formatter: " + formatter);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(rtime, formatter);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.err.println("Failed to parse device time [" + rtime + "] ");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2019-01-17T03:38:06Z[GMT]
```

You can use a different `DateTimeFormatter` in order to create different output.

---

In case you have influence on the input `String`s, you may be best adviced removing the `GMT` from it and only use `+00:00`, which can be used to create an `OffsetDateTime`.